# Customly set featured image in admin product add page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need a functionality for creating a featured image upload from admin product page and display preview.Can any one help me out here ?

Answer (score 0):

You need [ajax uploader](https://www.google.com/search?q=ajax%20uploader&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8).
It will upload the picture, and you can show before the form submitted.

Comment: it's ok for preview I can do it..But I need a hook for set a feature image.